# jQuery loop and .appendTo

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project where I first need to use the `<div>` as a selector. Then I need to create a loop that runs 10 times. After that, in the loop, I need to create an `<li>` with an anchor, using the loop's index as the anchor text. The final step is to use the `.appendTo()` method to add the li to the div.

I am not sure what code you would need to see to help out with this project. If anyone is willing to help, please let me know what you need to see as far as code goes and I will be happy to supply it.

Comment: The code you should post is the code you were trying to solve your problem. This is not the right place to ask for code out of nothing but to help with code that does not what you were expecting. If you are absolutely clueless, then you should start by learing the programming language and try to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Can you please show us your code? How much you have done? OR just post your desirable output.

Comment: *"...to add the li to the div."* -- You don't add an `li` to a `div`. You add it to a `ul` (*or `ol`*).

Comment: @RobertStettler I am trying to learn the programming language. This is part of a much bigger assignment I was given for a class project. I am sorry that I just was introduced to jQuery on Monday.

Comment: @RaviHirani Based on the comment left below yours, I think it might be best if I contact my instructor again for further clarification and attempt to solve the problem once again. I really don't have anything done, honestly. I have tried a couple of things, but nothing was working. If I still have questions after attempting clarification, I will then post my code. Thank you for your offer to help. It is much appreciated. It is nice to have people understand that not all of us are experienced in the same areas.

Comment: @Abhitalks Thank you for mentioning that. I will research the assignment a bit further.

Comment: @MelonySmith: I think you have got your answer. You'r welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following. Hope it will help.

```js
var html='<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     html += '<li><a href="#">Item ' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>';
}
html += '</ul>';

$('div').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide minimal code to show your efforts...

```js
var list = $("#div").append('<ul></ul>').find('ul');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
var a = parseInt( i , 10) + parseInt( 1 , 10) ;
    list.append('<li><a href="">'+ a +'  Are you happy now?</a></li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="div"></div>
```